# How to access array?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, controls, state-space

right now I'm working on `control.matlap.tf2ss` and I would like to access my array in my state space.

Here is my code

```
Gs = tf([P.l], [P.Jzz, 0, 0])
Cs = tf([P.Kp, P.Kd], 1)
Gcl = feedback(series(Cs, Gs), 1)
po = pole(Gcl)

num, den = tfdata(Gs)
sys = tf2ss(Gs)
print sys
```

**Result:**

```
A = [[ 0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]]

B = [[-10.58350385]
 [  0.        ]]

C = [[ 0. -1.]]

D = [[ 0.]]
```

How can I access array A, B, C, D?

Comment: thanks @PaulRooney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arrays of state-space models with variable numbers of states, use the syntax:

```
[a,b,c,d] = ssdata(sys,'cell')
```

Comment: merci beaucoup monsieur!

Comment: @Srikanth I editied your answer to add formatting. Just edit it again if you want to remove the edited icon.